# textbox format in 0.00 Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have to make three text boxes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H4fg.jpg)

First text box amount plus with textboxes, second the answer will show in the third text box in this format 0.0000000

And the answer text box already show this Digit 0.0000000

Example when I type in first textbox 5 the and second textbox type 5 then the amount will show in like this 0.0000010 please help me tell me some

```
Dim n1 As Double
        Dim n2 As Double
        Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, n1)
        Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, n2)
        Dim result As Double = n1 + n2
        TextBox3.Text = +result.ToString("00.00" + New String("0", 110))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you 7 digit fix, so if you add 5 and 5 then the result is 0.0000010, but if you add 24 and 124, it will give the result 0.0000128

```
Dim n1 As Double
Dim n2 As Double
Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, n1)
Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, n2)
Dim result As Double = n1 + n2
TextBox3.Text = (result / 10000000).ToString("0.0000000")
```

Comment: Thanks Dear Your Coding is Working 100% But Before the + Textbox3 will show like this 0.00000000 please tell me this

Comment: on form load procedure, please add expression: TextBox3.Text = "0.00000000"